# Please help, soft bricked my [US] [Sprint] Samsung Galaxy S6 SM-G920P

Tags: rooting, unbricking, unrooting

After around 5-6 hours this morning/afternoon, I've officially given up on fixing this on my own, and I've all but accepted my device to be an expensive paperweight.

I decided to make one last attempt at saving it by posting for help.

Problem: My phone has a feature called "FRP" (Factory Restore Protection), which is tied to one's Google account. Basically, if you have a Google Account on the phone, it locks the phone to any custom binary/custom OS/whatever.

Once I realized this, in order to root my phone, I went in and removed my Google accounts. Sure enough, this disabled the FRP Lock, and I was able to root my device.

After rooting my device, I re-added my Google accounts and went about my business for the next couple of weeks or so.

Just this morning, my phone was having issues charging, so I decided it'd be a good idea to give my phone a reboot. Big problem. It turns out I simply haven't ever turned off my phone since I rooted it. On top of that, I didn't think the FRP Lock would apply to booting the phone, I thought it only affected flashing new firmware. I was wrong.

After my phone turned off, red text appears at the top of the screen: "Custom binary blocked by FRP Lock".

This is the problem. It simply cannot boot. Because it cannot boot, I cannot remove the Google accounts to disable the lock and resolve the problem. Because the lock can't be disabled, I can't flash the phone's original firmware, because FRP Lock will stop anything and everything I try to do.

**tl;dr**: Soft bricked phone due to FRP Lock. Not able to restore original firmware, factory restore, or boot into phone's operating system.

**Important**: The phone turns on, and I have access to the recovery menu as well as "Download Mode"

### **What I have tried:**

- Factory restoring through the recovery menu, doesn't have any effect
- Flashing stock firmware through Odin (Nand write failure)
- Flashing a custom recovery environment (TWRP) through Odin (FRP Lock blocked this flash)
- ADB and Fastboot cannot recognize the device
- Tried to use Kies 3 and Smart Switch to "re-initialize" my OS or something. Both failed, saying that my phone wasn't compatible, and that my serial number was invalid (it was, in fact, correct)

---

The point here is that I've done everything, and literally everything has failed for one reason or another.

I feel like it is a possibility that if I attempted another stock ROM, then I might be able to avoid the Nand Write Failure. But again, I don't know.

Comment: http://forum.xda-developers.com/sprint-galaxy-s6/help/custom-binary-blocked-frp-lock-t3152054 did you try what this forum suggested?

Comment: I bumped into that post while I was searching wildly for a solution earlier. I'm currently downloading the latest stock firmware at the moment, 6.0.1. I'll see if this works in... hours, once the download is finished.

Answer (score 2):

Turns out that the stock firmware was failing to write because it was an old version, and Android doesn't like old versions, and it won't work.

I downloaded the most recent firmware (6.0.1) overnight, and sure enough, it flashed, and my phone is now functioning again.